# NodeJs + MySql connection pool ER_WAIT_LOCK_TIMEOUT sometimes only

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

I'm facing random issue its not happen everytime. i'm using nodeJs and connection pool. and in connection we have connection limit 50. and this is happening on INSERT only.

Does nested query blocks cause this issue ??

```
router.post('/userUpdateProfile', (req, res) => {

    let selectedSports = [1,2];

    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
    const sql1 = `call userProfileUpdate(some params);`;

    mysqlPool.query(sql1, [params], (err, response) => {

        const sql2 = `call userSportMapDeleteAll(?);`;

        mysqlPool.query(sql1, [params], (err1, response1) => {
            var sqlBlk = "INSERT INTO UserSportMapping (userId, sportId) VALUES ?";

            mysqlPool.query(sqlBlk, [tempSportArray], function(bErr) {
                //Here sometimes ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without releasing connection you are opening new one. You need to close/release connection when you finish your operation.

If this is an atomic procedure. execute them together instead of nesting it.

to execute multiple statements:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
connection.query('SELECT ?; SELECT ?', [1, 2], function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(res[0]); 
  console.log(res[1]); 

});
```

[check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54011512/nodejs-mysql-connection-pool-with-multiple-queries) for handling connections properly

**EDIT:**

```
connection.query('SELECT ?; SELECT ?', [1, 2], function(err, res) {
   // connection opened here
   ......

}); //connection released here
```

Comment: As document said with connection pool it will automatically close connection. we don't need to manually release it. BTW i'll try above approach to see will it solve issue or not.

Comment: what you are missing here is query block is not yet finished. which means connection is still active when you are executing other queries.

Comment: As i'm using connection pool. so i'm trying to use  mysqlPool.getConnection method and release after query block executed. and for next query same process.

Comment: I am facing same issue

Comment: @PankajCheema please check my own answer

Comment: If you feel that my answer is helpful for you, please upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried below solution and its worked for me. Thanks @Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu for pointing me that my script creating new connection without waiting for closing old one.

By using getConnection method. my issue resolved now.

```
router.post('/userUpdateProfile', (req, res) => {

    let selectedSports = [1,2];

    mysqlPool = mysql.createPool(mysqlConfig);
    const sql1 = `call userProfileUpdate(some params);`;

    mysqlPool.getConnection(function(conErr, connection) {

        if(conErr) throw;

        connection.query(sql1, [params], (err, response) => {

            const sql2 = `call userSportMapDeleteAll(?);`;

            connection.query(sql1, [params], (err1, response1) => {
                var sqlBlk = "INSERT INTO UserSportMapping (userId, sportId) VALUES ?";

                connection.query(sqlBlk, [tempSportArray], function(bErr) {

                    connection.release();

                });
            });
        })
    }):

}
```